# Custom RewriteRule not working with WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using WordPress Permalinks and custom redirects with parameters. Unfortunately, the custom redirects are not working.

My code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^old_folder/page\.htm$ /new_folder/page/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=de($|&)
RewriteRule ^old_folder/page\.htm$ /new_folder/page/? [L,R=301]
...
</IfModule>
```

Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Probably your request is being processed by first `<IfModule>` - try to move your custom `RewriteCond/RewriteRule` directives right after `RewriteBase` directive.

Comment: The first `<IfModule>` works well. Unfortunately I can't move the other redirects after the `RewriteBase` directive because WordPress would overwrite it

Comment: What you mean by "Wordpress would overwrite it"?

Comment: I think the idea here is to leave everything alone inside the WordPress comment tags - I understand that it scans that part. Best bet would be to create a new `RewriteEngine on`, `RewriteBase /` and your redirects *above* the `BEGIN WordPress` comment. Apache has no problem with repetition, and it would be required in this particular case. (I have seen this come up before, just for reference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your redirection before Wordpress Dispatcher:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^old_folder/page\.htm$ /new_folder/page/? [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=de($|&)
    RewriteRule ^old_folder/page\.htm$ /new_folder/page/? [L,R=301]
    ...
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Like @vitozev said otherwise the dispatcher will first catch the request and stop processing other rules because of the `[L]` flag.

You should just avoid to edit rules between `# BEGIN` and `# END` comments.